# Second Vlookup in Module Pulling Incorrect Column

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm having problem using a second vlookup in the same module but a different sub routine. The below is the code in the first sub routine

```
Sub ImportSchedUnschedData()

Dim combinedBook As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim combinedFilename As String
Dim combinedWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

MsgBox ("Select BRAM Report")

Set targetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Please Select an input file"
combinedFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set combinedWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(combinedFilename)

Dim lastRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input Sched-Unsched Split")

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("I15:I" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
                       "=VLOOKUP(RC[-8],'[" & combinedWorkbook.Name & "]Sheet1'!R1C1:R700000C2,2,0)"

    combinedWorkbook.Close False

End With

End Sub
```

The second vlookup I'm trying to use is below

```
Sub ImportRepurchaseData()

Dim combinedBook As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim combinedFilename As String
Dim combinedWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

MsgBox "Select Loss Information File"

Set targetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Please Select an input file"
combinedFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set combinedWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(combinedFilename)  

Dim lastRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input List Repurch")

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("D9:D" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
                       "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'[" & combinedWorkbook.Name & "]Sheet1'!R1C1:R700000C2,2,0)"

    combinedWorkbook.Close False

End With

End Sub
```

the problem I'm having is when I run the second vlookup column 'I' in my "Input List Repurch" tab is also being populated with a vlookup. My aim in the second vlookup is the below:

lookup value will be B9 in ThisWorkbook (The workbook with "Input List Repurch" Tab). Table Array will be A1:B100000 in combinedWorkbook. Col index number will be 2 and the range lookup as 0. The formula should be dragged down all the way until the end data in column M.

Any help would be appreciated?

Many thanks.

Comment: You've truncated your code - where is combinedWorkbook defined? Where are these two bits of code?

Comment: @SJR Apologies, I have now updated the code

Comment: OK, I can't see any obvious reason for that. Do you have any event code in the file - e.g. worksheet change? Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: @SJR Found the issue. Thanks for taking a look at this.

Comment: What was the problem?